# Limit of a sequence involving primitives

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = \begin{cases}\sin x  \sin (\frac{1}{x}) & x \neq 0  \\ 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

Let $F$ be the primitive of $f$ such that $F(0) = 0$. Considering $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ defined with $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_{n+1} = F(a_n)$, prove the convergence of the sequence and find out its limit.

My guess would be that the sequence has the limit $0$, proving the convergence by proving that $(a_n)_{n\ge0}$ is monotone and bounded or that it can be divided in such subsequences.

Of course, $F$ exists since $f$ is continuous, however, I don't know what can we tell about it. I observed that, if we take $g(x) = F(x)-x$, we have $g'(x) = f(x)-1 \leq 0$, so $g$ is decreasing. This means that $F(x) < x$ for $x > 0$ and $F(x) > x$ for $x < 0$, which maybe can be used to prove the monotony.

Can you help me with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are essentially using that $|f(x)| \le 1$, so that $|F(x)| \le |x|$. That is correct, but apparently not good enough to prove the convergence.

For $x > 0$ we have both $|f(x)| \le x$ and $|f(z)| \le 1/x$. Using the first estimate for $0 < x \le 1$ and the second estimate for $x >1$ we get by integration:
$$
 |F(x)| \le \begin{cases}
\frac 12 x^2 & \text{ if } 0 < x \le 1 \, ,\\
\frac 12 + \ln(x) \le x - \frac 12 & \text{ if } x > 1 \, .\\
\end{cases}
$$
$f$ is even so that $F$ is odd, therefore
$$
 |F(x)| \le \begin{cases}
\frac 12 x^2 & \text{ if } |x| \le 1 \, ,\\
 |x| - \frac 12 & \text{ if } x > 1 \, .\\
\end{cases}
$$

This shows that $a_n$ is eventually in the range $[-1, 1]$, and then $|a_{n+1}| \le \frac 12 a_n^2$ shows that the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Thanks, that was a smart way to use those estimations!